# Homomorphisms and primes

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that $f(a) = (a+p\mathbb{Z},a+q\mathbb{Z})$ is a homomorphism (p,q distinct primes)

I have shown

$f(a+b)=(a+b+p\mathbb{Z},a+b+q\mathbb{Z}) = (a+p\mathbb{Z},a+q\mathbb{Z})+(b+p\mathbb{Z},b+q\mathbb{Z}) = f(a)+f(b)$

I'm unsure how to show $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. I have said:

$f(ab)=(ab+p\mathbb{Z},ab+q\mathbb{Z})$ and $f(a)f(b)=(a+p\mathbb{Z},a+q\mathbb{Z})(b+p\mathbb{Z},b+q\mathbb{Z})$, but I'm not sure how to equate the two.

Further $f(1)=(1+p\mathbb{Z},1+q\mathbb{Z})=1$ the multiplicative identity of $f$

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is related to the fact that you do not make precise what are the domain and the co-domain of that supposed homomorphism.

Now I *assume* the domain is $\mathbb{Z}$ with usual operations and the codomain is 
$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z}$ with operations defined coordinate-wise.

Then $(a+p\mathbb{Z},a+q\mathbb{Z})(b+p\mathbb{Z},b+q\mathbb{Z}) = ((a+p\mathbb{Z})(b+p\mathbb{Z}) , (a+q\mathbb{Z}) (b+q\mathbb{Z})) = (ab+p\mathbb{Z},ab+q\mathbb{Z})$,

as

$(a+p\mathbb{Z})(b+p\mathbb{Z}) = ab +  p\mathbb{Z}$, and the same argument for the second coordinate just replacing $p$ by $q$. To see this note that $(a + kp)(b + lp)= ab +(bk+al +lkp)p =ab +k'p $ with  $k' = (bk+al +lkp)$. Thus the product of two elements in the classes $a+p\mathbb{Z}$ and $b+p\mathbb{Z}$ is in the class $ab+p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry, that is indeed the case @quid. Can you explain your final line? Intuitively, it is of course obvious, but a more rigorous approach is always more satisfying.

Comment: I assumed you saw that argument in disussions of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} $ is a ring. I added some details now.

Comment: Thanks @quid, can you confirm my argument for $f(1)=1$ is correct?

Comment: I would replace " the multiplicative identity of $f$" by "Since $(1+p\mathbb{Z},1+q\mathbb{Z})$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z}$ we see that $f$ takes the multiplivetive identity in the domain to the multiplicative identity in the co-domain."

Comment: Is the kernel $kerf={a E Z | a=0(mod p) and a =0 (mod q)}$

Comment: Yes this is one way to describe the kernel. In case $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes this is the same as saying $a$ is a multiple of $pq$; in general it would be $a$ is a multiple of  $lcm (p,q)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21074/discussion-between-user43290-and-quid).